# How can I change the background color of a cell button in the ObjectListView component

Tags: objectlistview

I have overridden the `DrawImageAndText()` method. Here is the source code of the ObjectListView(OLV) component.

```
protected override void DrawImageAndText(Graphics g, Rectangle r)
    {
        g.Clear(Color.Red);
        ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(g, r, text, textFont, textFormatFlags, false, buttonState);
    }
```

but I can only get a result of the following:
[It only changed the background color of a cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhESE.png)
but I want to now change the background color of the buttons in cell (instead of the whole cell).
Is this possible?

Comment: ButtonRenderer takes the windows theme into account. What do you want to achieve? It may not be the right choice in the first place (from a usability perspective) to put buttons into that column.

Comment: Thanks for your suggustion. I just want to change the background color of the buttons in cells. For example: change the color from light gray to red.

Comment: If you really need a custom button in there (think it over, there might be a better way), you probably have to use 'Button btn = new Button()', adjust the properties to your likings and put it in the parent control list of the desired cell. I believe the OLV provides some "Cell-Event" that provides you with the required arguments (cell dimensions for example) to allow you to place a control in there.

Comment: I have tried lots of "Cell-Event", but I found it difficult to place a control(Button) with those "Event". I thought the most probably Event might be "FormatCell", but I really could not find the parent control list of the desired cell in that Event.